# Post request sends null value to the database POSTGRESQL react node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When I am making a post request from react, it sends a null value to the database.

So, I put log statements everywhere and it seems that : on the server side in nodejs, the const {firstName} is undefined and I do not understand why. Also, I log the req on the server-side and the body is empty body:{}.

Client side: when I put log statement in try block on body, it log me this:  firstName: "abc" . So, the POST method does receive the body, but I do not understand where it gets lost?

When I console.log the state, it does set the state to the input value. However, when it sends data, the value is null.

I am using the following Reactjs, Nodejs, aws-rds-postgresql.

**This is sever-side in nodejs**

```
app.post("/users", async (req, res) => {
try {
    const {firstName} = req.body;
    console.log({firstName})
    const newUser = await pool.query(
        "INSERT INTO users (firstname) VALUES ($1) RETURNING *",
        [firstName]
    );
    res.json(newUser.rows[0]);
}catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}
});
```

**This is client side in react:**

```
const CreateEmployee = (props) => {
const [firstName, setEmployeeForm] = useState("");

const onSubmitForm = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
        const body = {firstName};
        console.log(body);
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/users", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            // We convert the React state to JSON and send it as the POST body
            body: JSON.stringify(body)

        });
        console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}

return (
    <Fragment>
        <h1 className="text-center mt-5">PernTodo</h1>
        <form className="d-flex mt-5" onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" value={firstName} onChange={e=> setEmployeeForm(e.target.value)}/>
            <button className="btn btn-success">Add</button>
        </form>
    </Fragment>
);
}
export default CreateEmployee;
```

Comment: I would try logging the entire `req.body` on the server side to better understand its structure. But from a glance, it looks like you're sending a body of structure `{ "employeeForm": <something> }`. The server is then trying to pull a `firstName` field out of this object, but as you can see, there is no `firstName` field. (I assume it's part of the `employeeForm`?)

Comment: I changed all to firstName. When I log the {firstName} on the server side, it gives me undefined. { firstName: undefined }

Comment: @AlexGrounds I rephrased the question

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

The issue was with the order of body-parser;
The order must be as follows with bodyParser on the very top.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require("express");
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line in nodejs worked for me:

```
app.use(express.json())
```